# Unable to fully flatten a face in Blender

Tags: modeling

I'm quite new to Blender and been practicing modifying meshes. I keep running into the same issue with trying to flatten ugly uneven faces. These faces are usually a product of a loop or bisect cut. Example:  [image: Mesh with uneven face]
I tried all of the following, which I gathered from other similar posts:

1. Transform to normals <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (experimented with different combinations X/Y/Z)
2. *Loop Tools -> Flatten*
3. *Mesh -> Cleanup -> Make Planar Faces*
4. *Face -> Solidify Faces*
5. *Face -> Beautify Faces*
6. *Object -> Shade Flat*

Nothing above worked for me to make this face flat. As far as I can tell the vertices are lined up to X-axis. The only thing that was producing the flat face is performing a boolean difference with a rectangle. Which did create a nice flat face, but it created another undesirable effect - the perpendicular faces were reshaped and made uneven.

Original shape, still showing the "ripples" on the large face: [image: Before boolean applied]

After applying boolean, "ripples" on the large face are gone but the perpendicular faces are now messed up: [image: After boolean applied]
This is another issue I'm looking to resolve since this is another problem I run into from time to time when I want to make a boolean cut.

I appreciate any advice to resolve either of the above.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It would help if you at least showed the object in edit mode, so that the topology was visible.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The result of text to mesh.  Mesh Modifier with Apply selected.  Edit Mode.

Consider the Remesh modifier. You will get quads. This may increase evenness.

There is also the Edge Split Modifier.

Answer (score 1):

To flatten a surface make all of the vertices and scale them to 0 on the axis you need. In the picture above you would press <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>+<kbd>$0$</kbd> (scale to zero on the $Y$ axis)

---

As an alternative to a mesh, you can create the shape as a curve with all the control points flat on the same plane, and give it some extrusion in the geometry controls.

[image]

Then you can choose to keep it as a 2D curve object and just fill it setting fill mode to both. Keep in mind that converting to curves will result in a topology filled with triangles, that is hard to work with later.

[image]

Or you can convert the unfilled curve to mesh.

[image]

[image]

Then select the edge ring and do grid fill.

[image]

and play with the settings until you have some nice quad topology.

[image]

[image]

Then do grid fill for the bottom as well.

Comment: I have tried all combos of S + so far and none worked to correct the face. I suspect the vertices are already lined up on a plain, but the fill continues to have ripples. Note: The mesh is not symmetric on both sides (the other side has a more complex shape that is not flat). I'm trying to flatten the bottom that will be on the printing plate.